# Why CAAnimation Rotation is returning to previous state

Tags: rotation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

I am using CAKeyFrameAnimation to do rotation of an arrow image.

Problem is that the imageview is returning back to the previos state after animation.

Code:

`CAKeyframeAnimation *rotation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
rotation.duration = 0.55;
 rotation.cumulative = TRUE;
 rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 if (isFlipRight) {
  rotation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)],
         [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)],nil];`

}
 else {
  rotation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)],
         [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)],nil];

}

[[arrowImageView layer] addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"transform"];

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before calling addAnimation..

```
rotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```